# How can I get this element to clear the image so it sits in middle off the page on top of the background

Tags: css, html

Hi I basically have this text block, which sits inside a Div that displays a confirmation. I want it to be in the middle of the page on top of the image instead of it being at the bottom. How can I do this?

This is my code, I want process to be in the middle of the page on top of the image

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="uft-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"">
    <meta name= "viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
    <link href="style/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>
<body>

        <h2 id="siteTitle">Westend</h2>
        <nav>
            <ul class="main_menu">
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="booking.php" >Booking</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

<div><img src="images/curtains.jpg" id="open"/> 
<div id="process">
</br>Hi <?php echo "'".$_SESSION['name']."'"; ?></br>
Your tickets have been booked for <?php echo "'".$_SESSION['production']."'";?>  
</br>Playing on <?php echo "'".$_SESSION['date']."'";?> at <?php echo "'".$_SESSION['time']."'";?> </br>
You are in <?php echo $_POST["zone"];?> in row <?php echo $_POST["row"];?></br>
The total cost is £<?php echo $_POST["quotation"];?></br>
Confirmation of your booking has been sent to: <?php echo "'".$_SESSION['email']."'"; ?></br>
</br>
Enjoy the show!
</br>
</div>




    <footer id="pageBottom">

        <p>&copy Westend 2015</p>
    </footer>




</body>
</html>
```

This is my CSS

```
#process {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: San-Serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #1a1a1a;
    background-color: #802000;
    width: 450px;
    height: 270px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 750px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding-bottom:2px;
    box-shadow: 3px 4px 5px grey;
    clear: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use absolute position as follows:

```
#process {
position: absolute;
top: calc(50% - 135px);
left: calc(50% - 225px); 
text-align: center;
font-family: San-Serif;
font-size: 20px;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #1a1a1a;
background-color: #802000;
width: 450px;
height: 270px;
border: 1px solid white;
padding-bottom:2px;
box-shadow: 3px 4px 5px grey;
clear: inherit;
}
```

here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKWqVr), hope this helps

Comment: Note that `calc() ` is supported on modern browsers, but not on some older one as for example ie <= 8.

Comment: True, you can make the trick using the absolute positioning and some  negative margin for that old fashioned browsers

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the right solution for your problem.

You may consider to add **.process** background-image with background-size: contain.

And then centerize the element .process with position absolute:

```
.process{
    background-image: url("../images/curtains.jpg");
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 450px;
    height: 270px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -225px;
    margin-top: -135px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using different approaches. One way to achieve your desired behavior is to put your div positioning out of the normal flow of the page, setting its position to absolute. This way you need also to set the properly positioning properties (top, left) to center the element within the page:

```
#process {
    position: absolute;
    width: 450px;
    height: 270px;
    top: 50%; /* distance from top border */
    left: 50%; /* distance from left border */
    margin-left: -225px; /* half the width */
    margin-top: -135px;  /* half the height */
}
```